# Are there any robust Clojure continuous integration options?

Tags: java, ant, maven, clojure, continuous-integration

I'm trying to integrate clojure into a continuous build .  Any suggestions for A clojure enabled system like Jenkins, that is capable of doing the work for me via a plugin? I've seen some ad hoc tutorials, but not sure if there is a clear accepted method. I notice that clojure itself is built using CI, and since it's a java dialect, I'm assuming maybe if no such options exist, then maybe I could wrap a clojure build as a maven / ant task....

Answer (score 8):

While Jenkins/Hudson is the most widely used for Clojure projects, you can use any CI system you like.

Clojure itself, all of the contrib projects, and various open source projects all use Maven to drive their builds and thereby can be hoisted into Hudson/Jenkins with relative ease.  [clojure-maven-plugin](http://github.com/talios/clojure-maven-plugin) is what you're looking for to mirror such a setup.

You can also use [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) with Hudson/Jenkins (or really any other CI system) just by shelling out to `lein` as necessary.  There is a somewhat clever way of setting this up through Jenkins itself [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Jenkins).

Finally, if you need ant, you can use [clojure-ant-tasks](https://github.com/alamar/clojure-ant-tasks).

Comment: Another vote for Jenkins; I've had great success using it with Leiningen using nothing but a basic shell command. The link above is one way to do it, but there's nothing wrong with simply installing leiningen via apt rather than a separate CI job.

Comment: @Chas, the link to "the somewhat clever way" is broken

Comment: Is there any reason you don't recommend palletops anymore ? (I've found this link : http://cemerick.com/2010/11/02/continuous-deployment-of-clojure-web-applications/ )

Answer (score 2):

You want to do all the work in either ant/maven/gradle etc. because you want to be able to easily build your project **locally** as well as on a CI system. Once you can build locally with a well known build framework, you just call the same tasks/goals in Jenkins and its super easy at that point, since Jenkins integrates nicely with most build frameworks like ant/maven/gradle.

Comment: So.... Is Leiningan an option for directly building ? It are you suggesting I should wrap Leiningan in maven/ant/gradle

Comment: Ant, Maven, Gradle, and Leiningen are peers, and the latter can be (and is) used independently of the others all the time.  Whether it meets your requirements is a separate matter (e.g. leiningen has no distinct notion of a release like Maven does, but neither does ant or gradle).  In any case, people call out to other build tools from their primary vehicle all the time, thus the maven tasks for ant, the maven antrun plugin, etc.  Leiningen is actually built on top of the maven ant tasks, so there are multiple levels of turtles. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As a data point, I use:

- **Maven** to build polyglot Clojure+Java projects
- **GitHub** for SCM
- **Travis CI** for continuous integration based off the GitHub source.

The important point is that by making the build work with Maven, you can hook into the standard Java-based CI tool ecosystem pretty easily. As far as Travis CI is concerned, it is **just another Java project** - Clojure is effectively treated as an extra Java library from the perspective of the build process. Here's the `travis.yml` config:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk7
  - openjdk7
  - openjdk6
```

Here's an example open source project using this approach:

- https://github.com/mikera/vectorz-clj

Answer (score 0):

Lambda CD is probably what you want. It allows you to write builds, and delivery pipelines in clojure. It is relatively new, and seems to be becoming more popular.
http://www.lambda.cd/